# Configure Custom Layout Renderer of nLog in .NET CORE 3.1 Web API Project

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, nlog, asp.net-core-3.1

I have configured nLog in my .NET CORE 3.1 Web API project which is all working fine. I want to use Custom Layout Renderer  ${hello-world} in nLog but unable to view result in Log file. Not sure what I am missing from the puzzle. https://nlog-project.org/2015/06/30/extending-nlog-is-easy.html

do I need the following configuration in my code?

```
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.LayoutRenderers.RegisterDefinition("hello-world", typeof(HelloWorldLayoutRenderer));
```

### Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();

        try
        {
            logger.Debug("init main");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
        }    
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
             {
                 logging.ClearProviders();
                 logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
             })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
        .UseNLog();
}
```

### Service Configuration

```
services.AddSingleton<ILoggerService, LoggerService>();
```

### DI

```
 containerBuilder.RegisterType<LoggerService>().As<ILoggerService>();
```

### NLog.Config

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="..\logs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate}| ${hello-world}"> </target>

<target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="..\logs\nlog-own-${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate}| ${environment: USERNAME}| ${hello-world}"></target>

<rules>
 <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />
 <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
 <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />    
</rules>
```

### LayoutRanderer class

```
 [LayoutRenderer("hello-world")]
public class HelloWorldLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    public string Config1 { get; set; }

    [RequiredParameter]
    public string Config2 { get; set; }

    [DefaultParameter]
    public bool Caps { get; set; }

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        builder.Append("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

### LoggerService Class

```
 public class LoggerService: ILoggerService
{
    private static ILogger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    private const string LoggerName = "NLogLogger";

    public void LogDebug(string message)
    {
        logger.Debug(message);
    }

    public void LogError(string message)
    {
        logger.Error(message);
    }

    public void LogInfo(string message)
    {
        logger.Info(message);
    }

    public void LogWarn(string message)
    {
        logger.Warn(message);
    }
}
```

### Web API Controller

```
 [ApiController]
public class DashboardController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILoggerService Logger;

    public DashboardController(
        ILoggerService _logger
        )
    {
         Logger = _logger;
         Logger.LogDebug("NLog injected into HomeController.....");

    }

  /// test logs 
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<HelloMessage> GetMessage()
    {
        Logger.LogInfo("Here is info message from the controller.");
        Logger.LogDebug("Here is debug message from the controller.");
        Logger.LogWarn("Here is warn message from the controller.");
        Logger.LogError("Here is error message from the controller.");
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Then try doing this:

```
var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup()
               .SetupExtensions(s => s.AutoLoadAssemblies(false).RegisterLayoutRenderer<HelloWorldLayoutRenderer>("hello-world"))
               .RegisterNLogWeb()
               .LoadConfigurationFromFile("nlog.config")
               .GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Requires [NLog.AspNetCore.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore/) ver. 4.9.3

See also: https://nlog-project.org/2020/03/28/nlog-4-7-has-been-released.html

Comment: many thanks, Rolf ... the solution did work for me ...